# Fluent NHibernate creating entities - why virtual

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I'd like to ask some questions about Fluent NHibernate as I'm developing in it almost a year but still there are some things which I don't get.

1. First questions is about entities as the title says. Why do I make them virtual?
2. A senior developer told me, that when I have a list of other objects in another one, I should initialize it in constructor, example:

   ```
   public class Category
   {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Equipment> Equipments { get; set; }

    public Category()
    {
        Equipments = new List<Equipment>();
    }
   }
   ```

   The first thing here is that I have a warning "Virtual member called in constructor" - I googled that but didn't really understood the problem with this. And the second part of question is: do I MUST initialize this list? Maybe I don't MUST but it's a good approach: if so, why?
3. Third question is about mappings, this is my way for above class:

   ```
   public  class CategoryMap: ClassMap<Category>
   {
     public CategoryMap()
     {
       Id(x => x.Id);
       Map(x => x.Name);
       HasMany(x => x.Equipments);
     }
   }
   ```

   And in some examples I have seen a one line of code:

   ```
   Table("Category");
   ```

   When do I need to specify the table?

----EDIT
Thanks for the answer, but now I have to clear something more, about the lazy loading. I read this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/652556/Can-you-explain-Lazy-Loading

And you can see a class Customer with private field _Orders and a public getter of that object (which also initialize the _Orders list). Can you please tell me if this is a better approach than mine? If yes, how should I change my code? (fields are virtual because of Fluent  NH.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Properties need to be virtual for `nhibernate` so that they can be substituted with proxies (required for [lazy-loading](http://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/various/lazy-loading-eager-loading.html))
2. You don't have to do that.However, it is a good practice to initialize collections in the constructor so that you don't get `null` suddenly in the code. For example , consider following code

   ```
   var category = session.Get<Category>(1);
   //without c-tor this line will throw exception as collection is null
   var totalEquipments = category.Equipments.Count();
   ```

   So either initialize it in constructor or keep writing this

   ```
   var totalEquipments = (category.Equipments == null) ? 0 : category.Equipments.Count()
   ```
3. This is to specify that entity `Category` should be mapped to table named `Category`. It can be used if entity name doesn't match default name or to make it clear where you want to store entities (see [fluent-wiki](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Fluent-mapping) for details on other attributes)